# How can I align certain elements of the numerator and denominator in a fraction?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, align, fractions

I have a large fraction containing very similar parts in both the numerator and denominator, but since the denominator has additional variables, the similar parts are not aligned together. Here is the picture:

[image]

I want is align similar parts of both numerator and denominator as in this (photo-edited) picture:

[image]

My source code:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    I_{rs} = \frac{ y^{2} I_{sc,ref}
        \bigg[
        1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref})
        \biggl]
    }
    {exp
        \left
        ( \displaystyle \frac{V_{oc,ref} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]}   {a \thinspace V_{t}}
        \right)  - 1 
    }
    %
    \label{eq:I_rs_trans}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated to the question but don't use math italic for multi-letter words, use `\exp` and `\mathrm{ref}` etc

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't align these as structurally aligning the terms seems confusing, but...

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\posA{0sp}\def\posB{0sp}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\makeatletter
    I_{\mathrm{rs}} = \frac{ y^{2} I_{\mathrm{sc}sc,\mathrm{ref}}
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\posA{\the\pdflastxpos sp}}% 
        \biggl[
        1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{\mathrm{op}}-T_{\mathrm{ref}})
        \biggr]\kern2\dimexpr\posA-\posB\relax
    }
    {\exp
        \left
        ( \displaystyle \frac{V_{\mathrm{oc},\mathrm{ref}}
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\posB{\the\pdflastxpos sp}}% 
\biggl[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{\mathrm{op}}-T_{\mathrm{ref}}) \biggr]}   {a \thinspace V_{t}}
        \right)  - 1 
    }
    %
    \label{eq:I_rs_trans}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

It takes two runs to stabilize. Note using `\mathrm` and `\bigl` on the left not the right.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your readers won't gain much, in terms of really understanding what's going on in the equation, if the two terms in square brackets are aligned. In fact, they might become confused, or at least distracted.

Your readers might, instead, appreciate something that's more compact:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:I_rs_trans}
    I_{\mathrm{rs}} = 
    \frac{ y^2 I_{\mathrm{sc},\mathrm{ref}}
            \bigl[ 1+\frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{\mathrm{op}}-T_{\mathrm{ref}}) \bigr] 
         }
         { \exp\bigl\{ 
            (a V_{t}{)}^{-1}V_{\mathrm{oc},\mathrm{ref}} 
            \bigl[ 1+\frac{\beta}{100} (T_{\mathrm{op}}-T_{\mathrm{ref}}) \bigr] 
            \bigr\}  - 1  
         }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```